# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: soundtouch.ST.setup:(IIIIFF)V at soundtouch.ST.setup(Native Method)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have already searched the stack overflow and none of them actually solves my problem.

I'm able to build .so files for my library and it is loaded into jniLibs directory. When I run the app, I get this

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: soundtouch.ST.setup:(IIIIFF)V
            at soundtouch.ST.setup(Native Method)**

I have spent 2 days and still couldn't figure out the problem.
Please can someone guide me through the issue.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!
My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.examples.anu.soundtouchexamplewithseekbar"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    ndk {
        moduleName "soundtouch-jni"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main' //set .so files location to libs
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK')            {
    def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').getNdkFolder()

    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
}

dependencies 
{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/main/jniLibs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

My Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
APP_STL := stlport_shared

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

MY_SOURCE_DIR:=soundtouch

LOCAL_MODULE:=soundtouch-jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=$(LOCAL_PATH)/soundtouch/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= soundtouch_ST.cpp\
              soundtouch-jni.cpp\
               $(MY_SOURCE_DIR)/source/SoundTouch/AAFilter.cpp\

LOCAL_ARM_MODE:=arm 
LOCAL_LDLIBS+=-lz -llog

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -I soundtouch/source/../include -D ST_NO_EXCEPTION_HANDLING -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

========
Adding my java and JNI signatures partially:

```
import android.util.Log;

public class ST implements AudioProcessor
{

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
   private static synchronized native final void putBytes(int track,
                                                       byte[] input,    int length);

private static synchronized native  final void setup(int track,
                                                     int channels, int samplingRate, int bytesPerSample, float tempo,float pitchSemi);
```

==========
My auto generated:.h file:
    /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
    #include 
    /* Header for class soundtouch_ST */

```
#ifndef _Included_soundtouch_ST
#define _Included_soundtouch_ST
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#undef soundtouch_ST_DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
#define soundtouch_ST_DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE 2048L
/*
 * Class:     soundtouch_ST
 * Method:    clearBytes
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_clearBytes
 (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);

 /*
  * Class:     soundtouch_ST
  * Method:    finish
  * Signature: (II)V
  */
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_finish
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);

  /*
  * Class:     soundtouch_ST
  * Method:    getBytes
  * Signature: (I[BI)I
  */
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_getBytes
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jbyteArray, jint);

 /*
  * Class:     soundtouch_ST
  * Method:    putBytes
  * Signature: (I[BI)V
  */
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_putBytes
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jbyteArray, jint);

 /*
  * Class:     soundtouch_ST
  * Method:    setup
  * Signature: (IIIIFF)V
  */
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_setup
 (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint, jint, jint, jfloat, jfloat);
```

======
   My implementation: soundtouch_ST.cpp

```
   #include "soundtouch_ST.h"
   #include "soundtouch-jni.h"

  /* cpp for class soundtouch_ST */

  #ifndef _Included_soundtouch_ST
  #define _Included_soundtouch_ST
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
  SoundTouchStream sts = new SoundTouchStream();
  #endif
 / *
  * Class:     soundtouch_ST
  * Method:    clearBytes
  * Signature: (I)V
  */
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_clearBytes
 (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint track) {
    sts->clearBytes(env,obj,track);
  }

 /*
  * Class:     soundtouch_ST
  * Method:    finish
  * Signature: (II)V
  */
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_finish
  (JNIEnv *, jclass obj, jint track, jint length){
     sts->finish(env,obj,track,length);
  }

 /*
 * Class:     soundtouch_ST
 * Method:    getBytes
 * Signature: (I[BI)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_getBytes
 (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint a, jbyteArray x, jint b) {
 (*env)->sts->getBytes(env,obj,a,x,b);
 }

/*
 * Class:     soundtouch_ST
 * Method:    putBytes
 * Signature: (I[BI)V
 */
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_putBytes
 (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint a, jbyteArray x, jint b) {
  sts->putBytes(env,obj,a,x,b);
 }

/*
 * Class:     soundtouch_ST
 * Method:    setup
 * Signature: (IIIIFF)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_setup
(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint a, jint b, jint c, jint d, jfloat f,    jfloat g) {
 sts->setup(env,obj,a,b,c,d,f,g)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its one of the following:

1)Your library isn't included.  Unzip the apk and make sure its inside.

2)You didn't load the .so file

3)The signature of the JNI function on the C and Java side don't match (the error is expecting it to take 4 ints and 2 floats in that order and return void).

4)You typoed a name in Java or C so they don't match.

Comment: It is only (3) or (4). The first two would provide a different message. The fact that the linkage appears is a clue that the library was already loaded and we are now trying to call a native method. If it was a library loading problem it wouldn't know the method signature yet.

Comment: I think it could still be 1 or 2 in the case of it calling a Java function declared native but not having loaded the library yet.  Although trying to load a library that isn't there would definitely throw a different error.

Comment: How do I unzip my .apk? I don't see any zip file in  my build/outputs/apk directory. This is the first time I'm implementing.  Thanks for your help

Comment: An apk is a .zip file.  Rename it and your OS should treat it like one

Comment: My java file signature:                                                                        private static synchronized native  final void setup(int track,
                                                         int channels, int samplingRate, int bytesPerSample, float tempo,
                                                         float pitchSemi);

Comment: My jni signature:JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_soundtouch_ST_setup
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint, jint, jint, jfloat, jfloat);

Comment: @GabeSechan I guess so, hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @GabeSechan,  I don't see any zip file in my build/outputs/apk directory. Could you please kindly let me know where to find the .apk? Thanks again!

Comment: I have a question. I have my main activity call that contains the static call, and I have my native method implemented in another package within a class. I have made sure that the main activity knows about this package (that contains the class with the native method) by doing the import statement.

Comment: I fixed my issue. The problem was my that my extern C JNI package name and the JNI.h header package name didn't match. I didn't see this problem as my extern c was in a different cpp. Thanks for giving me the suggestions.

Comment: you can buildApk and check AnalyzeApk

Comment: changed package name from a.b.c to net.surina.soundtouch but still I'm facing the same issue. can you help? @an96